# How to connect 12 devices with identical IPs on a single network when device IPs can't be changed?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have a customer who has 12 PLCs (Programmable Controllers) on his shop-floor. All these PLCs have identical IPs, and cannot be changed for some reason. My task is to access information from all these PLCs on a single PC. To network these PLCs, I thought of putting 12 routers having PLCs as the DMZ-hosts (LAN side), and the PC on the WAN side. But the problem is that I cannot add default Gateways in the PLC (it's configuration is inaccessible), and the above solution doesn't work without it.

Is there any other easy solution to this problem you can suggest?

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the netmask size for the network associated with  those PLC's and do they have unique mac addresses?

Comment: Alao, what protocol do you need to communicate with those devices using?

Comment: I'd really push back about not changing the IPs. I've worked with PLCs before in a decent sized manufacturing facility and never once had a circumstance where the IP could not be changed. I would guess they're trying to solve one problem with the static IPs and their solving it the wrong way.

Comment: - Mac addresses are unique.
- Protocol is Siemens proprietary S7 protocol.
- IPs cannot be changed because the PLCs are password protected by the Machine OEM. We are Siemens PLC system integrators .. so if there was a way, we would have done it.

Comment: There is no easy solution for this problem, a LAN is not designed to handle IPs that are not unique. I think it should work if you setup NAT on the 12 routers and make a port forward, But this is just an idea I haven't thought it through.